# Accessing OpenMQ remotely

Tags: java, openmq

I installed openMQ locally and it works fine. I used the following code to get the `QueueConnectionFactory` using a JNDI lookup.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///C:/objectstore");
Context  ctx = new InitialContext(env);
QueueConnectionFactory  myFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("MyQueueConnection");
```

The above returns me the connection factory from where I also access the `replyQueue` and `requestQueue`.

This is how I setup the queues

```
imqobjmgr add -l "MyQueueConnection"" -j "java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext
Factory" -j "java.naming.provider.url=file:///C://objectstore" -t qf -o "imqAddressList=mq://localhost:7676/jms"

imqobjmgr add -l "cn=DEVL.REQUEST" -j "java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSCon
textFactory" -j "java.naming.provider.url=file:///C://objectstore" -t q -o "imqDestinationName=requestQueue"

imqobjmgr add -l "cn=DEVL.REPLY" -j "java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSConte
xtFactory" -j "java.naming.provider.url=file:///C://objectstore" -t q -o "imqDestinationName=replyQueue"
```

My questions are:

1. How do I setup openMQ on a linux
   server so that I can access openMQ
   from a different server where the
   code will be running in a tomcat
   apache server (also a linux box).
2. What changes will I have to make to
   the code to get the
   `QueueConnectionFactory` from openMQ
   sitting on a different server ?

I'm not running openMQ in GlassFish, I'm running openMQ on it's own (imqbrokerd.exe).

Answer (score 2):

In all of my digging I haven't found anything to indicate that OpenMQ supplies a JNDI provider when it's used stand alone. It looks like that's provided by GlassFish. This means you'll need to use something like LDAP as an object store, which I haven't done yet.

Currently I've "cheated" by copying the .binding file (the one that's in c:\objectstore in your case) over to a filesystem that JMeter can see so I could reference it. As long as you use actual machine names, or IPs, instead of localhost that'll work but it's obviously not going to cut it for production.

On the Java side you could just drop JNDI completely and just instantiate `com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory` directly. I used Spring to inject the connection factory. Note that I had to include my own a very simple OpenMQConnectionFactoryFactory (stolen from https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/OpenMQSpringConnectionConsumer) because  com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory isn't a bean.

```
<bean id="connectionfactoryfactory"
class="myownlibrary.messaging.factory.OpenMQConnectionFactoryFactory">
  <property name="properties">
      <props>
          <prop key="imqAddressList">qa29-vm:7676</prop>
          <prop key="imqAddressList">qa30-vm:7676</prop>
          <prop key="imqReconnectAttempts">-1</prop>          
      </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionfactory"
 factory-bean="connectionfactoryfactory"
 factory-method="constructConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionfactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: when you connect directly with `com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory` how do you specify the URL?

Comment: Amazingly, I still have my .binding file laying around in spite of the fact that we didn't go with OpenMQ. Try something like this: 

`mq\://qa29-vm\:7676/jms,mq\://qa30-vm\:7676/jms`

That references two machines that I had set up as a cluster.