# connecting Mule ESB to OpenMQ broker

Tags: mule, mule-studio, openmq

I'm trying to connect Mule ESB to an existing OpenMQ broker. Building from the [mulesoft docs for openmq integration](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Open+MQ+Integration), I have the following flow;

```
<jms:custom-connector name="Custom_JMS" specification="1.1" 
                      class="com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory" 
                      validateConnections="true" doc:name="Custom JMS"/>

<flow name="EchoFlow" doc:name="EchoFlow">

    <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS"
                          connector-ref="Custom_JMS" responseTimeout="1000" 
                          topic="mytopic"/>

    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <logger message="#[message:payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

However, I get an error at runtime;

```
[02-26 10:54:08] ERROR DefaultMuleApplication [main]: null
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'acknowledgementMode' of bean class [com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory]: Bean property 'acknowledgementMode' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I have the feeling several elements have been left out of the example. Can someone tell me what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `custom-connector` needs a class that extends `org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector`. Try this instead:

```
<spring:bean name="connectionFactory" class="com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory"/>

<jms:connector name="JMSConnector"
    connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
    specification="1.1"/>
```

Comment: I see how I misunderstood the Mulesoft page, now - it doesn't show a <flow>. The above worked, but failed because the openMQ broker is not at localhost:7676 (the omq default).  I tried to supply the correct address with a property on the bean; 
  <spring:property name="imqAddressList"
                   value="mqtcp://192.168.56.4:30001/jms" /> 
but that caused "bean property 'imqAddressList' is not writable or has an invalid setter method..." I'm off to read spring docs and experiment, but perhaps you know the answer right off?

Comment: Found my answer in the answer to another omq question <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171457/accessing-openmq-remotely/8315138#8315138">here</a>.